# Unable to delete duplicate pagefile.sys

Tags: windows

I have one SQL server that contain two drives on it and both drives are on SAN. C drive contains OS and V drive Contain pagefile.sys file. I rebooted my server and both drives was unmapped on SQL server. Some How one drive came (the OS drive) and created pagefile.sys on C drive and then I rebooted my server remapped the v drive.

Now I have two pagefile.sys on C and V drive. But under Advance setting only V drive option is
checked as pagefile. How do delete duplicate pagefile on C drive.

It showing me that " the program is being used" while deleting the pagefile

Comment: That is not even the error that it should be throwing? Remapped? Just where is this V drive ? Most people would want a simple solid and direct path to a paging?  What is the OS ?  Did you try resetting the C paging back again, then remove it again?  The system can work with 2 paging files, the re-creation of it is stored in the registry (so even if you removed it if the registry defines it it will return) .  Are you sure you hit the SET button?  I often forget that myself.